# forge Viewer - How can we add CAMERA_CHANGE_EVENT for svg markups?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-data-management, autodesk-bim360

How can we add listener  CMERA_CHANGE_EVENT for markups drawn on a viewer? If we create a label against a dbid, we can store its coordinates and can apply worldToClient on coordinates to get new coordinates. But how this work for svg markups?

In my application, two ways user can associate rfi information.
1. by simply clicking a model obkject/dbid, I will let user add some textual information through a textbox and attach it as a label with that selected object/dbid.
this is working as label moves along with the selected object while camer rotation event.

Technically to get this done, am using function getObjPosition to get coordinates of dbid and store it in a label control and I pull those values during camera change event and updates current client coordinates using below function getClientCoordinates

```js
function getObjPosition(dbId) {
    const model = viewer.model;
    const instanceTree = model.getData().instanceTree;
    const fragList = model.getFragmentList();

    let bounds = new THREE.Box3();

    instanceTree.enumNodeFragments( dbId, ( fragId ) => {
        let box = new THREE.Box3();
        fragList.getWorldBounds( fragId, box );
        bounds.union( box );
    }, true );

    const position = bounds.center();
    return position;
}

function getClientCoordinates(positionCoordinates){
    var screenpoint = viewer.worldToClient(
                    new THREE.Vector3(positionCoordinates.x,
                                      positionCoordinates.y,
                                      positionCoordinates.z,));
    return screenpoint
}
```

2. In this scenarion, I am giving user to draw cloud markup and associate a label for the tetual information user enter on selection of markup.
   So to get coordinates am using below code
   var pos = markup.markups[0].getClientPosition();
   and tag the label with this created markup. It works. 
   For camera change event, the markups itself lose its position, so not sure how I will attach to the model and apply coordinates for label.
   Here another worrying part is, how I should get all the drawn markups on the model during camera change event

Hope my question is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

The `CAMERA_CHANGE_EVENT` works for the entire scene and whenever navigation occurs so there's no way to bind this to any specific object and it makes little sense to do so either.

If you are trying to move SVG markups to their new corresponding coordinates post navigation simply store their original world positions (using `clientToWorld`) before navigation and then use `worldToClient` to  get their new coords post navigation.

Comment: No am not trying to move svg. Here if I move the drawing by clicking and dragging, the svg markups will lose its focus and away from its orginal position wrt to the model

Comment: ... that's exactly why you need to move them accordingly to match the translation (movement) of the model and scene post navigation ...

Comment: wondering this is not supported automatically by svgMarkupScore

Comment: how do access markups on CAMERA_CHANGE_EVENT event?

Comment: how do you find markups and apply positions? Like labels you can do like var $eles = $("label[id^='mymk']"); 
                var DOMeles = $eles.get();
                for(var index in DOMeles){ //apply logic here}

Comment: .......... you can expose handles in your current scope or even on the window object to access the markups. jQuery is not a great option as it'd slow you down when rendering workloads stack up and you need to get performant, not to mention that it leads to spaghetti code ... Maybe try get some help from a senior member? This is turning into an elementary programming tutorial ...

Comment: Sorry, I think we both are on different page, I will elaborate my original thread to make it more clear as what the exact problem am facing.

Comment: ...... your question was clear and so was my answer. again try consult a snr member for help

Comment: I have added screen-shots above with markup and post camera-change as well. Only I wanted to know how we can manage markups as SVG DOM spec differs a lot from HTML DOM. Is there a way there or an example exactly shows this behaviour?