# How can i set markup text size according to the font size set to it the markup size is too large when zooming in?

Tags: autodesk-forge, markup, autodesk

**i need to change the Text Markup area size according to the text length and size** as it is getting too large when zooming in over pdf files .
Any help will be appericated.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you may need to watch the event of camera when the scene is changed. Please check this post:
[forge Viewer - How can we add CAMERA_CHANGE_EVENT for svg markups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60457516/forge-viewer-how-can-we-add-camera-change-event-for-svg-markups)

And you decide if you need to update the text size with the zoom scale . please check the other post about how to change font size of markup
[Forge MArkups Font Size and Thickness of Freehand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65595493/forge-markups-font-size-and-thickness-of-freehand)